# Changed Database Name -- Datatable Adapters broke

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, app-config

We've recently changed the name of the  SQL DataBase our WebApp is using. Now, each of the DataTableAdapters will update to the new ConnectionString.

Our setup is as follows:

1) Interface (WebSite Project)

2) Business Logic (Class Library Project)

3) Data Access (Class Library Project) ---> Contains many DataSet classes

The app.config of the Data Access project contains the only connection string. When creating each of the DataTableAdapters, the wizard points to it correctly. Now, we've had to change the ConnectionString, and all of the existing DataTableAdapters (about ~60) will not work.

Simply changing the ConnectionString has not worked. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Cannot open database "MyDataBaseName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'myWebAppUserName'.

Comment: Are you sure your login has permission to open the new DB?

Comment: Yes. However, "MyDataBaseName" is the old db name... Its not recognizing the new name. I've changed the connectionString AND gone through and manually replaced name in the xsd files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the  `Settings.Designer.cs` file. Its an auto-generated file that did not update after the normal updating/clean/build process.

Thanks Everyone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the connection string name in your config is the same as the one in the Settings File. Because in the generated code, when it initialzed the connectionstring it setting the connection string as follow :

```
private void InitConnection() {
            this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            this._connection.ConnectionString = global::ConsoleApplication4.Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString;
        }
```

Make sure that in your app config the name of your connectionString is the same. for example

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConsoleApplication4.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```